# How do a fetch race condition flag in React's useEffect hook between different calls?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, race-condition

This question might be a simple question, but I found nothing in here in my searches. How do different useEffect hook calls share the value in a fetch race condition flag?

What I meant is that, in this link: [race condintions in fetching data with useEffect hook](https://maxrozen.com/race-conditions-fetching-data-react-with-useeffect), the author uses a flag `active` to control race condition on fetches. I want to know how the previous (or next) call of the useEffect hook gets access to the returned value `false` from the clean up function (how is the value shared?). And how does it work in the javascript callstack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was very confused by this post as well. There's nothing magical going on with scopes, each clean up function only has access to the instance of `active` defined within its scope. The key detail is that although the useEffect function call has a long running API request, the function itself *returns almost immediately* with a pending promise. Therefore, when you click the fetch button a second time, the clean up function for the first request runs immediately, and set request 1's `active` to `false`.

Example timeline using the provided [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/beating-async-race-conditions-in-react-cleanupfn-45hlu?file=/src/DataDisplayer.js):

1. Fetch button press 1.
2. useEffect function runs: `active1 = true`, API `request1` sent.
3. *Pending* promise for `request1` returned *immediately*. `request1` has **not** completed.
4. Fetch button press 2.
5. Before useEffect function runs again, button press 1 clean up runs (even though `request1` hasn't finished yet!): `active1 = false`.
6. useEffect function runs again: `active2 = true`, API `request2` sent.
7. `request1` finally completes, but its results are ignored because `active1` was set to false in step 5.
8. `request2` finally completes, and its results are used, because it `active2` is still true.

[Forked CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/beating-async-race-conditions-in-react-cleanupfn-forked-7gl4mm?file=/src/DataDisplayer.js) with added `console.log`'s that helped me sort it out.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was struggling thinking that it was setting the active to `false` in some sort of "global" scope. To think that, in the end, it was just stopping previous requests from setting the state T_T.

Answer (score 0):

> How does the previous (or next) call of the `useEffect` hook get access to the returned value from the clean up function? How is the value shared?

It is not shared at all. Every effect execution has its own `active` value - it is only shared between the asynchronous `fetchData` function and the returned cleanup function, they are both closures over the same scope.

It's just that react cleans up the effect from the last render before running the effect again when the component state changes. It remembers the returned cleanup function (if any) while the effect is active, and calls it when the effect should end.

Comment: Srry for the tardiness, but I still don't completely understand how a different call of useEffect, with a different `closure`/`scope variables`, is able to get the modification that happened on the `active` variable in another `scope`/`closure`. I now understand there's no sharing, but how is the cleanup function return is used in another call of `useEffect()`?

Comment: Giving further context to my doubt: in the article the author mentions that *Additionally, if a component renders multiple times (as they typically do), the previous effect is cleaned up before executing the next effect*, and then the return function cleanup will set the `active` to false, but how is this variable the same as the one used in the other call? How is it changed? Maybe you've answered but I have not gotten.

Comment: It is not able to get the modification of the variable in another scope. It doesn't even really "use" the cleanup function of the other call. React remembers the active effect (and the dependencies, and the cleanup function) in its internal component state, just like it does for other hooks. When React figures out that it needs to run the effect again, it cleans up that remembered effect first.

Comment: I still don't understand... I'm feeling dumb now T_T. I believe I understand the steps that happens and the scopes. From what I understand, the clean up function of the second useEffect call is run after its async fetch is finished (receive a response), and then (what I can not understand) the active variable declared on the scope of the FIRST call is modified to false. Did your answer means that the fetchData scope between calls is the same? Or that it is the same as the useEffect call that has it in its body?

Comment: Have you read https://react.dev/learn/lifecycle-of-reactive-effects?